# http: read on closed response body - httptest.NewServer

Tags: go

I am trying to get to grips with testing using the httptest.NewServer and I am hitting a roadblock.

In my code I am making a GET request to an external API and I want to write a test for this using httptest.NewServer.

Here is my code making the request (main.go):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type HTTPClient interface {
    Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
}

type NewRequest interface {
    NewRequest(method string, url string, body io.Reader) (*http.Request, error)
}

var (
    Client HTTPClient
)

func init() {
    Client = &http.Client{}
}

func main() {
    url := "https://httpbin.org/get"
    GetData(url)
}

func GetData(url string) (*http.Response, error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    resp, err := Client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    responseBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
    fmt.Println(string(responseBody))
    return resp, nil
}
```

When I run this it works fine.

Here is my test file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func TestYourHTTPGet(t *testing.T){

    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, `response from the mock server goes here`)
    }))
    defer ts.Close()

    mockServerURL := ts.URL

    resp, err := GetData(mockServerURL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error 1: ", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    responseBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error 2: ", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
    fmt.Println(string(responseBody))
}
```

When I run `go test` I receive the error: `http: read on closed response body`. If I remove `defer resp.Body.Close()` from `main.go` the test passes correctly.

I am not sure why this is happening and was hoping that someone could explain what is going on here?

Comment: The `GetData` function reads the body to EOF and closes the body.  Remove that code if you want the caller to read and close the body.  Another option is to return `responseBody` to the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Cerise Limón says you call `resp.Body.Close()` twice and then try to read closed body. To fix yor code you can remove body processing from `GetData` function and do it outside `GetData` or return the body and do not read it in test.

main.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var Client = &http.Client{}

func main() {
    url := "https://httpbin.org/get"

    status, data, err := GetData(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(status)
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}

func GetData(url string) (status string, body []byte, err error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    resp, err := Client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err = io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    return resp.Status, body, nil
}
```

main_test.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func TestYourHTTPGet(t *testing.T){
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, `response from the mock server goes here`)
    }))
    defer ts.Close()

    mockServerURL := ts.URL

    status, data, err := GetData(mockServerURL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error 1: ", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(status)
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetData()`'s return is a pointer. You run `GetData()` in `main.go`, when retun, it will close the `resp.body`. And if you read it again, it cause `http: read on closed response body`

So if you want read the body again, you should not return `*http.Response`, you should clone the `resp.body` to return